# Translation of "sort of"

Tags: phrase, colloquial

In English, "sort of" is used to express half-hearted agreement.

> A: You're proud of your home country, right?
>
> B: Well, sort of.

In German:

> A: Sie sind stolz auf Ihr Heimatland, oder?
>
> B: Also, ***_*__**

How would you translate "sort of"?

Comment: Naja, so ähnlich.

Comment: I don't think that captures the meaning well in this context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few alternatives:

> Ja, schon.
>
> Ja, eigentlich schon.
>
> Also in gewisser Hinsicht schon.

Especially the last two translations indicate a limitation to your agreement, although not detailed.

Answer (score 3):

> F: Sie sind stolz auf Ihr Heimatland, oder?
>
> A: Mehr oder weniger

Answer (score 3):

> – Sie sind stolz auf Ihr Heimatland, oder?
>   – In gewissem Maße

or

> – Sie sind stolz auf Ihr Heimatland, oder?
>   – Gewissermaßen

Answer (score 2):

> A: Sie sind stolz auf Ihr Heimatland, oder?
>
> B: *So in der Art*.